# Alternative ways for developing for Android

Tags: android, cross-platform, appcelerator, app-inventor, rhomobile

I am an Android developer. I know of a few cross-platform development tools such as

- Rhomobile
- Anscamobile's Corona SDK
- Phonegap
- Titanium Appcelerator
- Google App Inventor.

If you know any tools apart from the ones I have listed please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note to closers:  this isn't subjective, and does not belong on programmers.se.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is [Monodroid](http://www.go-mono.com/monodroid/)...

Answer (score 2):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

Answer (score 1):

- Air for Android
- Monodroid
- Android scripting http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

[App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com) is fun. [This](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/sample-apps) is what I have

Answer (score 1):

Definitely try out Crank StoryBoard! it's got a complete GUI, it's really easy to use and very intuitive. If your looking to try things out, at least get an eval copy at http://www.cranksoftware.com/