# Development of an application on common SDK for Android, Blackberry and Symbian

Tags: android, blackberry, sdk, symbian

I need to develop an application on Android, Blackberry and Symbian in Java environment. For that I need to use only one common SDK for all OS. Is it possible, and how? Please tell me the software that is suitable for developing the application.

Answer (score 8):

That is a big question and this is a market that is quickly changing. There are a number of technologies that are trying to provide the "write once, run anywhere" development experience for smart phones. I don't know that you will find an answer in Java, but there may be a tool or framework that can help you.

Here is a short list of some of the ones I remember:

1. [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/home/)
2. [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
3. [Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/)
4. [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

Also, see some older Stack Overflow posts, like:

- [Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)
- [Developing cross platform mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application)
- [Alternative ways for developing for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735032/alternative-ways-for-developing-for-android)
- [Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/alternatives-for-ios-development-under-windows)

Updates:

- [Metismo](http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2011/05/cross-platform-mobile-developm.php)
- [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for immediate response..the SDK that u mention are not supporting all the OS. and do u know about the Kony plug-in which suports for ALL the three OS.Is it open sorce. i did nt find any plug-in downloda for that.can u plz help me to find that. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot develop the UI portions in Java using any of the cross-platform tools (at least for these platforms). For the non-UI portions, I think that BlackBerry is the most restrictive, since it is basically Java 1.3 (no generics). If you target this lowest common denominator, you can write the non-UI portions as a library shared among all the platform-specific products.

Answer (score 0):

With only one SDK i don't think it's possible.

You can develop a Web App that all can view probably.. but i see no other way.

Comment: what is web apps that we can use